# Django custom command error: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to create a command similar to `createsuperuser` which will take two arguments (username and password)

Its working fine in django 1.7 but not in 1.8.  (I'm also using python3.4)

this is the code I wrote

**myapp/management/commands/createmysuperuser.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Create a super user'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        if len(args) != 2:
            raise CommandError('need exactly two arguments for username and password')
        username, password = args

        u, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
        if created:
            u.is_superuser = True
            u.is_staff = True
            u.set_password(password)
            u.save()
        else:
            raise CommandError("user '%s' already exist" % username)

        return "Password changed successfully for user '%s'" % u.username
```

and when I try to run this command

`$ python manage.py createmysuperuser myuser mypassword`

I get this error

```
usage: manage.py createmysuperuser [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                                   [--settings SETTINGS]
                                   [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback]
                                   [--no-color]
manage.py createmysuperuser: error: unrecognized arguments: myuser mypassword
```

but when I dont pass any arguments it raises `CommandError` which is expected.

`CommandError: need exactly two arguments for username and password`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In django 1.8 you should [add arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#extending-management-command-arguments-through-command-option-list) to you command:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    ...
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('username')
        parser.add_argument('password')
```

`add_argument()` method of `argparse` is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method).

**UPDATE**: By default arguments are passed in the `options` parameter so the `handle()` method should look like this:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    username = options['username']
    password = options['password']
    ...
```

And you don't need to check the length of the `args` list - it is already done by `argparse`. This is the recommended method but if you want to use the `args` argument then you have to use the "compatibility mode" and name the added argument as `args`:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('args')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if len(args) != 2:
            ...
```

Read the "Changed in Django 1.8" side note in the [first chapter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management) of the docs (right after the `closepoll.py` example).

**UPDATE2**: Here is the full working example:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand    

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('username')
        parser.add_argument('password')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        username = options['username']
        password = options['password']
        return u'Username: %s  Password: %s' % (username, password)
```

Comment: `python manage.py createmysuperuser username myuser password mypasswd`
this command gives this error 
`error: unrecognized arguments: password mypasswd`

Comment: I've added `add_arguments` method just as in your answer and 
this below line to `handle` method
`username, password = options['username'], options['password']` 
am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the updated answer.  You should call the command like: `python manage.py createmysuperuser myuser mypasswd`.

Comment: I tried your code but still same error see my final code 
http://ideone.com/SbtYSB 

is there any problem with this?

Comment: You forgot to add the `add_arguments()` method from my first snippet.

Comment: Still not working same error, and infact you've written in this answer that I dont need `add_arguments()` method because bydefault  arguments are passed in the `options` parameter so.

Comment: I mean that by default parameters are passed in the `options` but not in the `args`.  And you should define the `add_arguments()` anyway.  See the full example in my second update.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. My 1.9 command accepted both args and options, and your solution does not support this.

Answer (score 7):

For minimal changes just add the method `add_arguments()` in Command class.

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')
```

You can continue to use `args` as before.