# Django management command for running scrapy crawl

Tags: python, django, scrapy

He I'm trying to create a django management command for running my scrapy script.
But I'm getting following error while running the script,

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\myProject\scraper\management\commands\extract_data.py", line 13, in run_from_argv
    self.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 314, in execute
    if options['no_color']:
KeyError: 'no_color'
```

This is my code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        self._argv = argv
        self.execute()

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        from scrapy.cmdline import execute
        execute(self._argv[1:])
```

Comment: at what location is the scraper located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/base.py#L271), `run_from_argv()` is responsible (amongst other important things like setting the `self._called_from_command_line` flag and  properly closing db connections after execution) for creating the argument parser, effectively parsing `argv`, **populate it with defaults for expected options** ("no_color" being one of them) and call `self.execute()` **with the parsed arguments and options**.

Here you're overriding `run_from_argv` without calling the parent's implementation - so none of the above is done - and directy calling `self.execute()` without a properly configured `options` dict.

The simplest solution is obviously to only keep your reference to `argv` and then call on the parent implementation ie:

```
def run_from_argv(self, argv):
    # keep a copy because the parent might modify `argv`
    self._argv = argv[:] 
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30230490/django-custom-command-error-unrecognized-arguments). You need to add the following to base command.

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')
```

and change the `run_from_argv` to the following:

```
def run_from_argv(self, argv):
    self._argv = argv
    self.execute(no_color=False)
```

Hence the full basecommand file will be as follows:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    # Need this from Django 1.8+ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761494/686255
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*')

    def run_from_argv(self, argv):
        self._argv = argv
        self.execute(no_color=False)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        from scrapy.cmdline import execute
        execute(self._argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this from google I was going at it from trying to test a management command. In order to that I've found that it is easier to use `call_command`. Here is the documentation link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#topics-testing-management-commands

It would look like the documentation

```
from io import StringIO
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test import TestCase

class ClosepollTest(TestCase):
    def test_command_output(self):
        out = StringIO()
        call_command('closepoll', stdout=out)
        self.assertIn('Expected output', out.getvalue())
```